# Is this problem related to Morse theory or not?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ be two real differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\varphi$ be a homotopy between them, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2\times[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\qquad\text{with}\qquad \varphi(0,x,y)=f(x,y),\qquad\varphi(1,x,y)=g(x,y)
\end{equation}
Let $P_f=(x_f,y_f)$ be a critical point for $f$ and $P_g=(x_g,y_g)$ be a critical point for $g$. I would like to define a "critical path" $\gamma$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$ with the property that $\gamma(0)=P_f$, $\gamma(1)=P_g$ and $\gamma(t)$ is a critical point for $h_t(x,y):=\varphi(t,x,y)$ for all $t$. Of course $\gamma$ is not unique because of creation/annihilation of critical points during the homotopy. What concepts and subjects shoud I study to tackle this problem? Is it related to Morse theory?

Comment: Offhand this does not look related to Morse theory (because the critical points may be degenerate here, and because the focus appears to be on the functions, not on the topology of their domain), but maybe it depends on the mathematical intent. Is the goal merely to construct a homotopy $\varphi$ with a path of critical points, or does $\varphi$ need to satisfy any properties other than this? (If not, there are easy and probably uninteresting constructions of $\varphi$.)

Comment: The goal is precisely that. Why do you think it's both easy and uninteresting?

Comment: If there are no constraints on $\varphi$, we can pick our favorite smooth real-valued function $h:[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ that is $1$ at the endpoints and $0$ on (say) $[1/4, 3/4]$, and define $\varphi(t, x, y) = h(t)f(x, y)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1/2$; $\varphi(t, x, y) = h(t) g(x, y)$ for $1/2 \leq t \leq 1$. Then we can find a path from a critical point $p$ of $f$ to a critical point $q$ of $g$ by staying at $p$ until $1/4$, moving smoothly to $q$ by $3/4$, and staying there until $1$.

Comment: To emphasize, I mean _my understanding_ of the question is uninteresting. The preceding shows what we can do if there are no constraints on $\varphi$. On the other hand, I don't see offhand how to get a non-trivial problem by imposing constraints, e.g., that $f$ and $g$ be Morse and that $\varphi$ be Morse. (That looks too restrictive, as it precludes critical points splitting and coalescing.)